# Using strace, how do I use it to get the network and serial calls

Tags: linux, bash, serial

I have a python program that runs in the background, what I need to know for debugging purposing is that I need to see what calls it is send and receiving for serial, network and to stdout.

I know that if I want to see stdout, I need the parameter of "-e write", but what about the other ones? And I need it to output all 3 of them from a single command, as it is going to be part of a console app I am making.

Answer (score 1):

In general you'd run `strace` without `-e` at first (eventually on a smaller/lighter program with similar operations) and redirect the stderr to a file, then peek inside the file to select the minimum set of `-e` options you need.

For your particular case I ran it on a `wget` invocation (looking for network stuff only) and I determined these options would be of use: `-e socket,connect,close,write,read` (drop `read` if you're not interested in the receiving side).

With these options `strace` shows stuff like this for the network calls:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("74.125.202.121")}, 16) = 0
write(4, "\26\3\1\0\302\1\0\0\276\3\1\374\2\223/\332\3545\34\2628u3-3hT\25s\"\310\215"..., 199) = 199
read(4, "\26\3\1\0]", 5)                = 5
read(4, "\2\0\0Y\3\1U\251X\245#\313\3544a\17\372\276\340^%\177y\270asQ\255^\7B\212"..., 93) = 93
...
close(4)                                = 0
```